# Hide cursor in fullscreen mode using Qt 4.8?

Tags: qt, qt4, mouse, mouse-cursor

I'm in a ArchLinux with OpenBox and I want to hide the cursor on fullscreen inside a Qt 4.8 application. I am aware about some other question about it but no one works every time: sometimes the cursor is hiding, sometimes not. I didn't managed to understand exactly when the problem occurs but I think that maybe is it related with the screensaver because if I test my application just after the computer is restarted the mouse cursor is no visible (and it is what I want) but if I test this feature during the day the mouse cursor is still visible in fullscreen.

This is my code:

```
void MainWindow::toggleFullScreen()
{
    if(!this->isFullScreen())
    {
        this->showFullScreen();
        #ifdef Q_WS_QWS
            QWSServer::setCursorVisible( false );
        #endif

    }
    else
    {
        this->showNormal();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see [How to hide mouse pointer in Qt app at startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44005653/608639)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I want to hide the cursor on fullscreen ...

You could set the cursor to be the blank cursor:

```
widget->setCursor(Qt::BlankCursor);
```

Also, as the docs state:

> Some underlying window implementations will reset the cursor if it leaves a widget even if the mouse is grabbed. If you want to have a cursor set for all widgets, even when outside the window, consider `QApplication::setOverrideCursor()`.

So you can call:

```
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::BlankCursor);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a program named ***unclutter*** that hides the mouse pointer. Here's an ArchLinux package:

https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/unclutter/

I currently use it on an embedded system for hiding the mouse cursor on a touchscreen.